# Custom ConfigurationSection type not loading correctly

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

Every time I do a `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("registeredPlugIns")` for this custom section I receive this error:

An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for registeredPlugIns:

> Could not load type 'Engine.PlugInArch.PlugInConfigurationSection'
>   from assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Why is it trying to load the type from `System.Configuration` and not the assembly that I ask it to?

Here is my Section code:

```
namespace Engine.PlugInArch
{
    public class PlugInConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("plugIns", IsDefaultCollection = false),
         ConfigurationCollection(typeof(PlugInCollection), AddItemName = "addPlugin")]
        public PlugInCollection PlugIns
        {
            get { return this["plugIns"] as PlugInCollection; }
        }

    }
}
```

And here is my app.config

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    <section name="registeredPlugIns" type="Engine.PlugInArch.PlugInConfigurationSection, Engine"/>
    </configSections>
        ...
    <registeredPlugIns>
       <plugIns>
           <addPlugIn DllName="ProcessorPlugin.dll"/>
       </plugIns>
     </registeredPlugIns>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is your dll called Engine.dll? I think not and that is where the problem is.

OK, run procmon from sysinternals. Set the filter to your process name and also filter for result="NAME NOT FOUND". You will see entries where it is looking for Engine.dll or Engine.exe. See where it is looking for it and it is likely the file needs to be copied to the running folder.

Comment: It is actually Engine.exe Would that matter? They type is in the assembly that is referencing this app.config.

Comment: When I set it to look for just Engine, it looks for Engine.dll (which doesn't exist). When I set it to Engine.exe it looks for Engine.exe.dll. Ugh. I guess I'll just have to move this type out of the .exe.

Comment: I added allowExeDefinition="MachineToApplication" and that seemed to do the trick. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `<section name="registeredPlugIns" type="Engine.PlugInArch.PlugInConfigurationSection, Engine"  allowExeDefinition="MachineToApplication" />` *still love you .Net!*